# What does the Map version of Tween Max.js do?

Tags: javascript, animation

Just wondering what the Map version of Tween.js Does?

[image]
I'm trying to use this [The Normal Tween.min.js] in a project, on github
[openSrcSpaceGame](https://github.com/MistaKistHur/OpenSourceSpaceGame)
but I can't get the animation to work.

HTML:

```
<svg width="500" height="200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     style="z-index:55;">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Gradient">
      <stop id="stop1" offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
      <stop id="stop2" offset="0.3" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="Mask">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="200" fill="url(#Gradient)"  />
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="200" fill="#480048" />
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="200" fill="#C04848" mask="url(#Mask)" />
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
}
```

Js:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-tween/5.5.10/Tween.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-ZCFdsmjscnDMNwJZKekA5B6BgwuR1NtN2NLH2CDhVzw="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>


/* :>> Tween Section from Css tricks...... */
    TweenMax.fromTo("#stop1", 1.5, {
      attr:{offset:-1}
    }, {
      attr:{offset:1},
      repeat: -1,
      yoyo: true,
      ease:Linear.easeNone});

    TweenMax.fromTo("#stop2", 1.5, {
      attr:{offset:0}
    }, {
      attr:{offset:2},
      repeat: -1,
      yoyo: true,
      ease:Linear.easeNone});
```

I tried wrapping it inside DOMContentLoaded,
But this didn't help,
Also moved the CDN script about but that didn't help either, looks like the Tween block is missing a bracket somewhere but I'm unsure where to put it.

Just to clarify the CDN script was at the bottom of the body & the tween block was in a bigger script block further up the page inside of a DOMContentLoaded evt listener. The gradient block is showing, but its not animating & has blocked rendering of other svg elements I had at the top of the page. knowing me its probably something stupidly simple.

Just tried the CDN link in the head, but still getting TweenMax is not defined in the console?

The only difference I can see is that the original is using Gsap.TweenMax from a CDN created in 2014:  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js
& I added the latest Es6 TweenMax.min.js. from 2019.

Comment: What do you mean by "Map version"? If you wonder about `Tween.js.map`, that's the sourcemap of the minified js file.

Comment: Still doesn't mean a whole lot to me, whats the difference from normal & source map? is it necessary to include both & if so, in which order?

Comment: Uh… https://www.mattzeunert.com/2016/02/14/how-do-source-maps-work.html https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map

Comment: Only read the first few bits so far, but whats the point of using const if its actually compiled to var, thanks for the resources I will continue reading through them....